# Apache won't stop using old project files / refuse to remove old cache

Tags: apache, caching, svn, browser

I am using Apache httpd on localhost to connect to the project I'm working on, I have been deleting web cache when website is showing the old project instead of the new one. However recently the project is stuck on an outdated version and restarting/clearing cookies won't work with the user I'm assigned.

I tried using another user with my project and it works just fine. I recently did use `svn revert` which may have caused my user to get stuck with old project, but I'm not sure that's the problem.

Commands I use to start and stop:

```
sudo service httpd start
sudo service httpd stop
```

Any advice or tips are greatly appreciated.

Update: I managed to get the page to update the html, however my JavaScript won't load which I suspect is due to another user being stored and thus not accessing the database I use which leads to nothing being generated.

Comment: It is unclear what you ask, since your question is very vague. What _exactly_ do you mean by "using apache httpd on localhost to connect to the project"? This _might_ refer to some web client accessing the svn repository, but that is just a guess.

Comment: @arkascha I dont know much about how svn works and since revert undoes a change maybe the server got the old project to register to the user im using, since the project works fine with another user. Sorry if i sound ignorant im pretty new to this.

Comment: The apache http server does know nothing about subversion and there certainly is no connection between some user and a specific project or anything like that. I could imagine that you are simply using outdated URLs, maybe the browser auto completion gets in your way? Anyway: I would ask you to add more specific details to your question (there is an `edit` link below it): what connection is there between apache and svn? Some web app, or are you using http URLs within your cli svn client? _Tell us!_

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I got everything to "work" again by accident, I made some edits to PHP and my PHP crashed because of a syntax error. When I fixed it back to original stage it was working again. It most likely is related to a user the previous owner created that caused the problem.

Comment: your reply is not self explanatory. please will you tell all readers what you mean by PHP. because i think its php.ini file that you edited and stuck for syntax error.

Comment: @suren: see the first line, "posted on behalf of the [Original Poster]". That means that although I posted it, it is not my material (it was originally edited into the question, so I moved it here). Please make your remark as a comment to olof.r under the question.

Answer (score -1):

Just clear Temporary files

In windows CTRL+R and type %temp% and delete all the files it will help to you

Comment: i use linux fedora. I've tried clearing cache stoping and starting also logging out, but it still wont show the current project should i try and check if the browser is running in backround and somehow stores old cache?